# Gateway Timeout error on Gerrit GUI

Tags: git, gerrit

I am getting Gateway timeout error 504 while accessing Git branches from a Gerrit GUI. And this is happening for only one of my repositories Which is biggest in size among all.Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like proxy issue. Try to bypass it

```
git config --add remote.origin.proxy ""
```

Comment: No. it is empty. as you are trying to bypass it.

Comment: No you can open the terminal and just run the command. It is not specific to any directory

Comment: Its Again giving me the same Gateway Timeout error. Any suggestion?